# Find all the words in string except one word in python with regex

Tags: python, regex

I'm working with regex in python and I'd like to search for all the words in a string except one word.
Code:

```
import re
string = "The world is too big"
print re.findall("regex", string)
```

If I want to get all the words except for the word "too" (so the output will be `["The", "world", "is", "big"]`), How can I implement this in regex?

Comment: Not every string problem is a regex problem. Split on whitespace, then filter your list to remove the items you don't want.

Comment: If you want to play around while learning regular expressions, the online testers are pretty convenient: https://regex101.com/ is one.

Comment: `' '.join(list(filter(lambda w: w != 'too', string.split())))` or `' '.join(w for w in string.split() if w != 'too')`

Comment: matches all strings except too: `^(?!too$).*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need to use regex for this task, simply use `split` and `filter`:

```
sentence = "The world is too big"
sentence = list(filter(lambda x: x != 'too', sentence.split()))
print(sentence)
```

Comment: I'm not crazy about the use of `string` for a variable name here, especially when it becomes a list. Please consider renaming your variables.

Comment: sure, I only used it because of OP's example

Comment: In Python 3, `filter` returns a generator, so you'd have to do `print(list(sentence))`, or something like that to actually see the words.

Comment: @not_a_robot I'm pretty sure the OP's using python 2, but adding a list() wouldn't hurt

Comment: @abccd I just added my comment for future folks coming to this question who may be using 3 :)

Answer (score 1):

Delete 'too' in string, then split string.

```
re.sub(r'\btoo\b','',string).split()
Out[15]: ['The', 'world', 'is', 'big']
```